# Rope / Ropemacs - Auto Import feature

Tags: python, emacs, ropemacs, rope

I'm using Rope and Ropemacs to transform my emacs as a IDE for Python. I have a problem with the `rope-auto-import` feature. I read in the doc that I must add modules that I want to autoimport like this:

```lisp
(setq ropemacs-autoimport-modules '("os" "shutil"))
```

But I want to autoimport **all** modules installed on my computer. How can I specify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I miss the same feature but unfortunately it is not possible to tell rope/ropemacs to enable autoimport for all modules. You have to manually add the modules to the `ropemacs-autoimport-modules` variable.

See the last messages of this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/rope-dev/browse_thread/thread/6d4778e7bedc096d